# Creating a Regex to match "Body: Margin 0"

Tags: css, regex

I want to create a regex, in order to find out if an entry exists.
The Entry is in a CSS File.
Unfortunately different developers tend to write them in different manners, so I want to create a regex, that matches all this individualities.
I hope somebody can help me.

```css
body {
  margin: 0; }

body 
{
  margin: 0; 
}

body{margin:0;}
```

Comment: You could apply a code-formatter to the input file first, that will tame the syntax. Also if you want to check if a rule is apllied in an HTML document, you may check with `Window.getComputedStyle()` (see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables that could makes your regexp fails: `body` could have an id, a class, and/or be part of a bigger list. You could have comments, the ";" could be missing, you could have multiple rules inside.

Unless you want to match *exactly* the three strings above, I strongly suggest to use a css parser that returns an AST. Something like: https://github.com/csstree/csstree

Comment: The File is uploaded on the Server and gets checked while uploading. It is not possible to use Javascript. At least I don't know how right now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work for your examples, as well as any other valid synthax I can think of :

```
^\s*[\.\#]{0}body(\s|\n)*\{[^\}]*(\s|\n)*margin(\s|\n)*\:\s*0\s*\;[^\}]*\}
```

Try here : https://regex101.com/r/GbIbdE/1